# Angular Reactive forms Validate a control from directive

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a number input in an Angular Reactive form, I got a directive to limit the number of decimals, and that are working fine, I am looking to implement auto-correct as part of that directive, which is also kind of working but not the validation.

```
<input type="number" formControlName="TestPercentage" id="TestPercentage" max="100" step="0.25" numeric [decimals]="2"/>
```

ts file

```
 this.form.addControl(formConstants.markupPercentage, new FormControl('', [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100)]);
```

I am using the decimal number directive from https://gist.github.com/ahmeti/5ca97ec41f6a48ef699ee6606560d1f7 and the part where I am changing value

```
if (Number(currentValue) > Number(this.el.nativeElement.max)) {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = parseFloat(this.el.nativeElement.max).toFixed(this.decimals);
    this.el.nativeElement.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

this one is making the value to max value but not removing the invalid class/ not revalidating or the new value assigned in the directive is not getting validated.

[image]

How can I trigger the validation once I changed/ corrected the element value?

Comment: if can help you to your purpose, the form has the valueChanges method, that is an observable that emits an event every time the value of the control changes. you can listen the valueChanges of a single control too like `this.form.get('controlname').valueChanges.pipe(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I resolved this issue is by passing the abstract control to the directive and setting value using setvalue method, which resolved the issue.